# How to run an ASM file for Assembly program?

Tags: assembly, compilation, bios, dosbox

I used to run an ASM file with **DOSBox0.74**, but it doesn't work anymore - because the F10 key stuck to the whole program completely.

I heard there are **other softwares to run ASM files** for Assembly programs but I didn't find any. How to find and install a new software and successfully run ASM files?

Updates:
Hi @Peter Cordes, @Ped7g - I added some screenshots of the case, is that helps to know what is my problem?

[8086 folder files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/203PO.png)

[MASM files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weYuT.png)

[screenshot of DosBox after I preesed F10 and is stucked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPDzh.png)

Comment: You have to assemble asm source to create an executable before you can run it.  For DOS, you want either .COM or .EXE format, or a boot sector that you boot instead of an OS.  What does your source look like?  Not all assemblers use the same syntax for the same machine code.

Comment: the dosbox can run only the DOS executable, and the F10 was probably for the SW being run inside the dosbox, maybe you had some old DOS development environment there? It's not clear from your description, what you had and what it does now.

Comment: First thing  - someone edit my question and I can't contact them and message them.

Comment: Second, how can I post a screenshot to show you all what I'm talking about ??? there is no such option dudes !? !!!

Comment: @EladHatan You can reach everyone you want just by starting your comment with an **@** character followed by their user name. Just like I did right now to contact you.

Comment: @EladHatan To post a screenshot you first start editing your post. There you click on the 6th icon in the toolbar (a picure of a mountain under the sun). From there you follow the prompts to upload your picture (GIF).